# Replacing form button with an image and adding value on top

Tags: html, forms, button

I haven' t found a way in doing this. What I want to do is to create my own button images (actually 2 images for each button for rollover effects) and also add caption on top of the image. The first part is very easy but I cannot find a way for the caption part. My project includes many buttons each one with a different value displayed on top (100 form buttons - one for each number 0-99). So it is not good idea to create 200 images and then edit them to put the numbers on top. 
What I would really like to know is if I could use an image instead of the default button and add a value on top like in the form buttons:

then I could put this line inside a loop and populate my page dynamically. So I would only have to create 2 images for my buttons.

Any ideas?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user711250 for your hover images look at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just actually did this for a project a few days ago.  Here is the CSS, sample image and html of what I did.

```
<style>
.rollover,
.rollover:visited {
    background: #FFF url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWGMJ.gif) no-repeat scroll left 0px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 64px;
    height: 27px;
}

.rollover:hover {
    background: #FFF url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWGMJ.gif) no-repeat scroll left -27px;
}
</style>
<input type="button" class="rollover" name="btn_1" value="1" /><br />
<input type="button" class="rollover" name="btn_2" value="2" /><br />
<input type="button" class="rollover" name="btn_3" value="3" /><br />
<input type="button" class="rollover" name="btn_4" value="4" /><br />
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I will have to modify it though to meet my expectations. But it is a nice start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS which takes that image as a background image and use that css with some component may be for example `<a>` tag to display text on it.

CSS:

```
.myClass{
  background: url(/iamges/img.png);
  //-- some other css values
}

.myClass:hover{
      background: url(/iamges/img_hover.png);
      //-- some other css values
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a onClick="func()" class="myClass">1</a>
```